# How to protect a website managed by keycloak from abusing the "forget password" as a way to spam a user?

Tags: keycloak

I'm working on a website that will be managed by keycloak, there is an option to configure a realm to have a "forget password" functionality.

My question is how to protect against the option of abusing the "forget password" option by sending multiple requests and spamming a user ?

I was checking KeyCloak forums and documentation but couldn't find any information about it. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: By implementing a captcha? How do other websites handle these things?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way of doing this, as far as I know, unless you write some rule in your smtp server for stopping the server sending mails to the same user beyond a concrete threshold in a time interval. There are some plans to [include a captcha](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4945) in the flow, for the 5.x version, though.

Comment: Thanks @Xtreme, Is that mean that all KeyCloack based applications are exposed to this vulnerability ? are there any other WA's ?

Comment: It seems like a basic feature that the Team should have priorized a long time ago..